# Android: XML can't find other views by id

Tags: android, xml, find, resources, android-relativelayout

suddenly, really out of nothing I started to have an issue with my RelativeLayout. The problem is that it doesn't want to recognise other view that are in this RelativeLayout defined with IDs:
The error message (on line **android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/editText3"**) is: **Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBaseline' with value '@id/editText3').**

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/editText3"
        android:text="Predaj: "
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView3"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't understand what seems to be the problem - I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, restarting PC, deleting and recreating the whole files (R.java as well) but the error just wouldn't go away. When I delete this line of code, everything works just fine (Except for aligning). I have a feeling that it is because the "textView3" is defined before "editText3" but it worked like this for the past few days.
Thanks for advice - very appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Francesco Gatto. It really helped creating the variable for EditText already in TextView so the code now looks very similar but actually works.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >



     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Cena: "
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I have created the edittext variable already when assigning layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText" and then in EditText I used the same id (not creating it again).

Answer (score 1):

did you try to Clean the project?

Or try to write +@id in alignbaseline

Comment: @+id in alignBaseline really did the trick. Thanks a lot. I'll share a detailed answer as soon as I will be allowed by the system (too low rating).

Answer (score 0):

reference it after you declare it and see if that calms the error. Also your refering to things before there declared. It seems you want  some visual text and then a box so the user can edit text to the right of the textview.  In RelativeLayouts just let the very first view lay itself out automatically or you can lay it out wtih respect to the parent. ie. ( android:layout_alignParentLeft). In RelativeLayouts the firstview we use as our starting reference point other then the parent container.  I adjusted your code, please advise if it makes sense:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/editText3"
        android:text="Predaj: "
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried it but then the same error occurs on the line android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1" in EditText

Answer (score 0):

I know that it has been late but it might help someone with the same problem.

Place the `EditText` above the `TextView`. It won't affect the look of what you're doing because it's a `RelativeLayout`.

What happens is that, in simple terms, Gradle scans every line of your code and since it doesn't find the ID already that you have mentioned, it shows an error.

The previous answers are also correct but this is much simpler to implement.